# Lost connection to "iPhone” when running app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am running my app first time in xcode 6.0.1 given below error occur.

Restore the connection to "iPhone 6" and run "AppName" again, or if "AppName" is still running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > AppName.

How do I solve this issue?

And I am maintaining Services integrating classes at a separate class.

And after getting Response from services I am getting response in my main class using protocols.

Like below my code.

Please help me.

### my code:-

```
- (void) GetCallService2: (id)MainResponse{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    });
}
-(void)BsicEroor:(NSString *)ErrorString{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    });
}
```